# Where should 'app:layout_behavior' be set?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, vertical-scrolling

Should it be set at the [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) sibling's parent or at the first Scrollable View inside its sibling?

---

With [Material Design for Android](http://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html), there are [Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) that let us work with the behavior of the layout depending on its surroundings, one of them is the [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html), as [this CodePath guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) mentions:

> CoordinatorLayout extends the ability to accomplish many of the
>   Google's Material Design scrolling effects. Currently, there are
>   several ways provided in this framework that allow it to work without
>   needing to write your own custom animation code.

The one I'm interested in now is:

> - Expanding or contracting the Toolbar or header space to make room for    the main content.

So, we would use the [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) with a [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) with `app:layout_scrollFlags` set and another [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) sibling to the [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) with `app:layout_behavior`.

My question is: in what exact ViewGroup (or maybe View) should we put that
`app:layout_behavior`?

---

So far, I've tried with (And they have all **worked**, and they are all siblings to the AppBarLayout):

- Scrolling View
- First ViewGroup inside a Scrollable View
- ScrollView inside a ViewGroup

And this one didn't work:

- ViewGroup with no Scrollable View children.

---

There are multiple examples online, but none of them really state where should you put it, like:

http://www.ingloriousmind.com/blog/quick-look-on-the-coordinatorlayout/
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/becoming-material-with-android-design-support-library/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Check this link:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

> `AppBarLayout` also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to
>   know when to scroll. The binding is done through the
>   `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` class, ***meaning that you
>   should set your scrolling view's behavior to be an instance of*** `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`. A string resource containing the
>   full class name is available.

They mentioned about that, it should be the `View` which will be shown under the `AppBarLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <!-- Your scrolling content -->

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

> **My question is:** in what exact `ViewGroup` (or maybe `View`) should we put
>   that `app:layout_behavior`?

And in this link: http://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

> Next, we need to define ***an association between*** the `AppBarLayout` and
>   **the View that will be scrolled**. Add an `app:layout_behavior` to a
>   `RecyclerView` or any other View capable of nested scrolling such as
>   `NestedScrollView`. The support library contains a special string
>   resource `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` ***that maps to
>   `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`, which is used to notify the
>   `AppBarLayout` when scroll events occur on this particular view***. The
>   behavior must be established on the view that triggers the event.

Comment: "View capable of nested scrolling" is important i guess, if you disable nestedScrolling on recyclerView it does not work

Comment: @Jemshit Iskenderov is right never set recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); you are just using recycler after AppBarLayout, or your recycler view is not inside NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you added the **appbar_scrolling_view_behavior** field in your **String.xml**

```
<!-- The class name to the ScrollingChildBehavior required for AppBarLayout -->
<string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
```

And as everyone knows we just can use this like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSomeList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Its just for info not OP answer.

Comment: The design support library already defines that string resource. There is nothing gained by redefining it in your own resources.

Comment: May be you are right .I forgot , but I faced problem and resolved it after adding this in string.xml.

Answer (score 11):

`app:layout_behavior` should be set to those views which are direct child of Coordinator layout

Comment: What is coordinator layout actually? pls dont mind.., I m little new to android dev.

Comment: @eRaisedToX Its nothing but a FrameLayout with some adding features..Check it once https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html

Comment: Also SwipeRefreshLayout

Answer (score 8):

> AppBarLayout also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to
> know when to scroll.

This description from Android is woefully incomplete and caused me hours of wasted time.

*Scrolling sibling* is a misnomer and need not be a scrolling view of any type.

For example, below my `AppBarLayout`, I'm using a `ViewPager2` that will render a `Fragment` that will render a `Scrollview`, so I needed to set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` directly on the `ViewPager2` in the main layout, **NOT** the deeply nested `Scrollview` in the fragment layout.

I also have no use for scrolling the `AppBarLayout` or any of its children on or off the screen, so I falsely assumed I could get away with not setting the `app:layout_behavior` anywhere.

**Wrong.**

This reveals a more insidious issue: `AppBarLayout` **requires** the *scrolling sibling*, yes. But not **just** to "know when to scroll", but to actually adjust the size of the sibling to fit properly on screen alongside it!  Otherwise, the sibling maintains its configured size and will be nudged downward offscreen by the height of the `AppBarLayout`! You can even see this in Android Studio's layout editor.

Long story short: If you're going to use an `AppBarLayout`, you **need** to mark one of your views with `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`, whether it's a scroll view or not.

Answer (score 3):

I had to add the following to the gradle file otherwise it gave me a compile error.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Hope this would help some others too!

Answer (score 3):

For someone who uses `CoordinatorLayout` with `FragmentContainer` and `AppBarLayout`:

- It is really good to set the `app:layout_behavior` also on the container (not just on `NestedScrollView` or `RecyclerView`). It deletes unnecessary bottom margin of the `FragmentContainer` and guarantees that the appbar hides when the keyboard is shown.