# Toolbar overlapping other contents android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a BaseActivity which contains the navigation drawer.
So , now my other activities will extends from the baseActivity to get the navigation drawer as well.

This is my app_bar layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.matt_pc.dissertationv2.HomeActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <include
            layout="@layout/content_home"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    <com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my content_main

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home"
    />
```

My navigation drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@mipmap/background"

    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"

        android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is my toolbar is overlapping my contents.See below.
[image]

Any help on this?

Comment: you are using `AppBarLayout` incorrectly see this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout     and also this may help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181299/where-should-applayout-behavior-be-set

Answer (score 0):

Try delete your `AppBar` theme and toolbar `popupTheme`:

- `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"`
- `app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that either using two `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` or, when replacing the `Fragment` would cause the issue.

So, if you have something like this in your app (when trying to show `Fragment`):

```
..replace(android:R.id.content, yourfragment())
```

Change the view to your `FrameLayout` id `content_frame`:

```
..replace(R.id.content_frame, yourfragment())
```

And use the layout it as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I am not using any fragment :(

Comment: FrameLayout in there is used to show Fragments inside CoordinatorLayout. Perhaps making it a bit clear of why you’re using FrameLayout in there might help to give you the right solution. Anyways, did you try my pasted layout?